# OrderBy list LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

My Model contains List of `Offers`. offers having `SpecialOffers` value `true` should be orderd by `RGU` and `OfferPriority`. The offers having `SpecialOffers` value `false` should be ordered by `InitialPrice`(descending) only.

I tried the following query, it achieves the first part i.e ordered by `RGU` and `OfferPriority` but this is applied on  the non `SpecialOffers` too.
What should be the query to achieve these two tasks?

```
List<OfferModel> providerOffers = Model.Offers
    .Where(x => x.Provider.ProviderCode.Equals(provider))
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.SpecialOffer)
    .ThenByDescending(t => t.RGU)
    .ThenBy(p => p.OfferPriority)
    .Select(x => x)
    .ToList();
```

**EDIT** `SpecialOffer` is a boolean property attached to each offer that determines whether an offer is Special or not

Comment: So, do you need to sort 2 different collections?

Comment: ```.Select(x => x)``` <- useless

Comment: The Collection is same. `SpecialOffer` Property of each offer determines whether its a SpecialOffer or not

Comment: One collection U can order only by one way. Or U want something like ```.ThenByDescending(t => is_special ?  t.RGU : default_value)``` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first group by this property to get two groups which you can order separately:

```
var offers = Model.Offers.Where(o => o.Provider.ProviderCode.Equals(provider));
var offerGroups = offers.GroupBy(o => o.SpecialOffer);
var specialGroup = offerGroups.Where(g => g.Key == true)
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.InitialPrice);
var nonSpecialGroup = offerGroups.Where(g => g.Key == false)
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.RGU)
    .ThenBy(p => p.OfferPriority);
var result = specialGroup.Concat(nonSpecialGroup).ToList();
```

Due to LINQ's deferred execution these queries will be executed as a single sql query.

---

Disclaimer: i'm not sure if the generated sql will keep the order of the groups, normally you have to apply the `ORDER BY` on the outer query which is the final `CONCAT`, it's translated to a `UNION ALL`. Then the easiest would be to use `Linq-To-Objects` with `AsEnumerable`:

```
var result = specialGroup.AsEnumerable().Concat(nonSpecialGroup.AsEnumerable()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. Very nice explanations. Thumbs Up (y)

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your lists based on their type, you can´t order two different lists with the same statement:

```
var result1 = model.Offers.Where(x => x.SpecialOffer).OrderBy(x => x.InitialPrice);
var result2 = model.Offers.Except(result1).OrderBy(...);
```

If not all elements within your list that are not a `SpecialOffer` should be sorted by `ProviderCode`, `RGU` and `OfferPriority` you can use this for the second list:

```
var result2 = mode.Offers.Where(x => !x.SpecialOffer)
    .Where(x => x.Provider.ProviderCode.Equals(provider))
    .OrderByByDescending(t => t.RGU)
    .ThenBy(p => p.OfferPriority);
```